# mod_rewrite conditions not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to setup an apache URL rewrite / redirect that will change URL
from

```
http://<domain #1>/work/<domain #2>/*****
```

to

```
http://<domain #1>/work/<domain #1>/*****
```

I tried following , but the rewritecond is not working in comparing 2 variables.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !$1 
RewriteRule /work/([^/]+)/(.*)$  /work/%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [R=302,L]
```

appreciate your help!

Comment: Are the domains actually known or are they going to be variable?

Comment: Domains are going to be variable ,( anyone from 100s of virtual hosts)

Comment: Will all domains rewrite to one main domain, or will they all rewrite back to themselves? As it is, you'll have a redirect loop.

Comment: they all will redirect back to themselves and when I tried without condition, went to redirect loop.

Comment: btw, I am running apache 2.2

Answer (score 0):

`$1` has no meaning in the `RewriteCond` directive.  You might try something like this:

```
RewriteCond expr "! '%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '/work/%{HTTP_HOST}*'"
RewriteRule /work/([^/]+)/(.*)$  /work/%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: "RewriteCond exp",can I use this in Apache version 2.2 ?

Comment: @DDD I believe it should be.  I wasn't able to determine version differences on this item by looking at the documentation.

Comment: @Mike, the condition doesn't seems to be working, I was getting a redirect loop.

I also tried following to deny the access if it's a wrong url, but denies all the time . So looks like the condition never matches.

RewriteCond expr "! '%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '/work/%{HTTP_HOST}*'" [OR]
RewriteCond expr "! '%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '/work/%{HTTP_HOST}*'"
RewriteRule /work/([^/]+)/(.*)$  - [F]